# Как я могу изменить URL через add_rewrite_rule()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как из ссылки вида:

http://testsite/city/sochi/?listing_type=apartment

Я могу получить http://testsite/city/sochi/apartment

Метод предоставленный ниже не срабатывает для меня, в чем моя ошибка?

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('^city/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?city=$matches[1]&listing_type=$matches[2]', 'top');

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас внутри скобок может быть и `/`, что ломает регулярку. Вот рабочий код:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^city/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?city=$matches[1]&listing_type=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
```

Вызов `flush_rewrite_rules()` очень ресурсоемкий, его нельзя ставить на каждую загрузку страницы. Он должен использоваться только в хуках, указанных в `register_activation_hook()` и `register_deactivation_hook()`.

Для того, чтобы код начал работать, надо сбросить redirect в браузере. Для этого открыть Dev Tools (F12), а потом правой кнопкой мыши на обновление страницы и в меню выбрать Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверить, что код сработал, можно в отладчике. Видим, что `$this->matched_rule` содержит наше правило, а результирующий запрос находится в `$query`. Файл `apart.php` - это `mu-plugin` для теста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное - это сработало для меня!
Но теперь на странице  http://testsite/city/sochi/apartment - выводятся все элементы, принадлежащие apartment. Но когда ссылка выглядела /city/sochi/?listing_type=apartment, то на странице отображались apartment, который принадлежат городу sochi.

Comment: Это уже выходит за рамки вопроса. Вывод осуществляется вашими плагинами или темой.

Comment: Ух как зачёно расписал. Прям на кейс и FaQ тянет. :) (я б только добавил, что редиректы лучше проверять внешними сервисами типа bertal.ru)

Comment: @SeVlad мы, крестьяне, с модными сервисами не знакомы. Внутри xdebug живём ))